# ARCore android how to detect face and blink eye programmatically?

Tags: android, detection, arcore, face-detection

There are a lot of information about face detection api, but I can't find any information about moving lips feature for android.
There is one for iOS [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor/blendshapelocation)

Can anyone suggest something ? Thank for advance!

Comment: For the face detection, eye blink, smile, and face movement, you can use Google vision-
https://developers.google.com/vision
But it doesn't have moving lips detection.